# If I flip a fair coin 100 times, is the sample space the same as if I only flip it one time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A fair coin can only be heads or tails. Does that mean the sample space for 100 flips is the same because each outcome can only be heads or tails.

IE

S = {h,t}

Comment: Well, no.  You could get $100$ heads or $100$ tails.  Or the first one could be heads and the next $99$ tails.  Or...

Answer (score 4):

The sample space for 100 flips is made of the $2^{100}$ different possible outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is the set of all possible events.

In this case you have $2^{100}$ possible events.

Each event is a string of H and T of length $100.$

Comment: My follow up question is what is the Pr[0]? is that the first event so is it 1/100?

Comment: It is one of 2^100 events therefore the probability is $1/{2^100}$